# How do we know the choice of base does not effect the area of a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, area

Question:

- How do I know area of a parallelogram is well defined? That is, how do I know choice of base and relative height does not matter?

My original question had to do with triangles which is more of a headache (*three* choices of bases and relative heights) but I suppose I should tackle the smaller mountain first.

[image]

I am having a difficult time convincing myself that the choice of base does not matter when proving the area of a parallelogram. I know that given a parallelogram of base $b$ and height $h$ its area is $b\cdot h$. The tools I have are the following...

(P1) Every region has an area given by a positive real number.

(P2) Given a square of side length $s$, its area is $s^2$.

(P3) If the interiors of two regions do not intersect, then the area of their union is the sum of their areas.

(P4) Congruent regions have the same area.

(T1) Given a rectangle with base length $b$ and height $h$, its area is given by $b\cdot h.$

For T1, the area of a rectangle, there is no worry about ambiguity for choice of base. For instance in rectangle $FECD$ below, if I choose $b_1=DC$ then $h_1=DF$, where if I choose $b_2=DF$ then $h_2=DC$... Thus $$b_1\cdot h_1 = (DC)(DF)=(DF)(DC)=b_2\cdot h_2$$ hey thats good! No Ambiguity!

But what about for parallelograms?

The idea for the standard proof given base $DC$ and height $CE$ above is given in purple. Virtually forcing rectangle $FECD$ to show up with constructing parallel lines and $HL\cong$ on $\triangle EBC$ and $\triangle FAD$. But I have no idea how to show that the area is the same if we were to allow $DA$ the base and $DG$ the height.

I need to show that $$(EC)(DC)=(AD)(DG)$$I'm at a loss. Any guidance would be amazing. I am trying to avoid coordinate geometry and only prove this with the most basic postulates in euclidean geometry (mostly to avoid circular reasoning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a "proof" that $Area(ECDF) = Area(ABCD)$ that requires you to show first that
$\triangle AFD \cong \triangle BEC$, after which (if $\triangle AFD$ does not intersect $\triangle BEC$) you know how to show that $Area(ECDF) = Area(ABCD)$.

But how do you know that $\triangle AFD$ does not intersect $\triangle BEC$?

To complete a proof that requires that $\triangle AFD$ does not intersect $\triangle BEC$, you must first prove that $\triangle AFD$ does not intersect $\triangle BEC$.
This is a relatively simple fact, but I think it takes more effort to prove it that it does to just prove that the quadrilaterals have equal area without making that assumption.

The proof I think you need is the proof requested by [Why do these parallelograms have the same area](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3455189/139123).
Your requirement is to prove the special case where one of the two parallelograms is a rectangle. But proving the general case also proves the special case. And the general case is no harder to show than your special case.

Comment: Yup! Love the post you linked to its what I was looking for. I will still dedicate some thoughts to the triangle case now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: triangles $BCE$ and $CDG$ are similar (and $AD = BC$).

Comment: Similarity, in the book I am using, has not been mentioned. Is there a way to avoid similarity?